# Embed iFrames in Google Search Page

Tags: iframe, google-chrome-extension, google-search

Does google allow inserting inline iFrames on the google search page with the help of a chrome extension?

Comment: Any site allows it if the iframe points to an html file inside the extension, see [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: Does that mean it needs to be a static html file bundled in the extension?

Comment: Yes. Inside that file you can create any DOM you want or add nested iframes. However, this is a worst case workaround which is not needed on google search site. As you can see in the main URL response, there's no `content-security-policy` header so there's no restriction on what resources/iframes you may add there.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for.